# something wrong with urdf in rviz

Tags: rviz, urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello guys

> 

I am new to ROS,and i use hydro-ROS and ubuntu 12.04LTS , i tried to run a navigation demo in "ROS By Example",but when i input

> $ rosrun rviz rviz -d `rospack find rbx1_nav`/sim.rviz

,the robot model in rviz show something wrong

some parts of the urdf model show error like : No transform from[XXX] to [odom]

is something wrong with the sim.rviz?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/101301/something-wrong-with-urdf-in--rviz/) by [vigor](https://answers.ros.org/users/8811/vigor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-11-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Running rviz is not enough to see your robot, you must also provide the body relative position using `robot_state_publisher` for instance. I recommend you use instead:

`roslaunch urdf_tutorial display.launch mode:=robot.urdf`

It will load the necessary parameters in the parameter server, start the `robot_state_publisher` node as well as rviz for you.

See the
[URDF tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Building%20a%20Visual%20Robot%20Model%20with%20URDF%20from%20Scratch) for more information.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) with karma: 4478 on 2013-11-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0